# SwiftUI WatchOS-Only Run Error due to HealthKit

Tags: swiftui, watchos, watchos-6

I am getting this error only when Health Kit is enabled and I am running on a real device.

```swift
2023-01-30 19:40:27.907022-0700 Watch App[381:50291] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)") 

2023-01-30 19:40:27.907136-0700 Watch App[381:50291] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "Default Configuration") 

2023-01-30 19:40:28.483274-0700 Watch App[381:50291] [scenes] unable to send desiredFidelity:Never response to desiredFidelityAction:<BLSDesiredFidelityAction: 0x15ebc010; info: 0x0; responder: <_BSActionResponder: 0x15eba5e0; active: YES; waiting: NO> clientInvalidated = NO; clientEncoded = NO; clientResponded = NO; reply = <BSMachPortSendOnceRight: 0x15ebd320; usable: NO; (381:0:send-once xpcCode) from (354:0:send-once take)>; annulled = YES;>
```

I have made sure that all key pairs required for HealthKit are enabled in the info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, I copied the files into a new project. I still get the same error code, but at least healthkit works properly now.

Going to assume it is an apple/simulator/xcode issue.